# How to convert from long+TimeUnit to Duration?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, timeunit, chronounit

I'm migrating some signatures from `f(long dur, TimeUnit timeUnit)` to `f(Duration duration)`, and would like to implement the former with the latter.

Being on Java 8, I can't find any API to easily convert the `long`+`TU` to a `Duration`, the only idea that comes to me is to do something ugly like:

```
static Duration convert(long dur, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
  switch (timeUnit) {
    case DAYS:
      return Duration.ofDays(dur);
    case HOURS:
      /* alternative, but (again) I don't have an easy conversion from TimeUnit -> ChronoUnit */
      return Duration.of(dur, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    case ..... /* and so on */
  }
}
```

Or did I miss some API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Java 8 there is a roundabout solution `:\` (we unnecessarily convert from our TU -> millis (or whatever unit) -> Duration) like this:

```
long dur = ...
TimeUnit unit = ...
Duration result = Duration.ofMillis(unit.toMillis(dur));
```

---

Caveat emptor with extremely large values though, `Long.MAX_VALUE` days cannot be correctly converted into `long millis` (compared to `Duration`'s ctor that does throw when trying to init with such a value):

```
final long millis = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE); // ouch
final Duration dur = Duration.ofMillis(dur);
System.err.println(dur.toDays() == Long.MAX_VALUE); // returns 'false'
```

Comment: Duration's Javadoc states: `To achieve this, the class stores a long representing seconds`, so actually we got into undefined behaviour with the above corner-case.

Comment: `Duration` holds two `long` values: one for *seconds*, another for *nanoseconds*. There's no issue with conversion of `TimeUnit.DAYS` to *milliseconds* (if you're OK with this precision), unless are dealing with astronomical problems (the number of years to cause `long` overflow in *milliseconds* should be very large). The real problem is `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(100000)` will give `0` - the precision has been truncated to *milliseconds*. Whether this issue is important depends on your requirements.

Comment: And depending on your data, you can make use of `Duration.ofNanos()`. To overflow `long` representing the number of *nanoseconds*, the duration need to be greater than `290` years. So I guess most likely you can use this option. Fair enough, it's a good find if you don't want to introduce a dependency on a third-party library in your project.

Comment: Right, I concentrated on the upper-bound too much. This could be worked around with using nanos (as in `Duration.ofNanos(unit.toNanos(dur))`), but then we just reduced arguments to about 100k days (`Duration.ofNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE).toDays()`). Should just upgrade Java to get rid of this mess.

Comment: There are loots boons in higher versions. For instance, modular system of Java 9. And more longer you're postponing the migration of the project, the more difficult it would be in the future.

Answer (score 9):

## Java 9+

You can use static method [`Duration.of(long, TemporalUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/time/Duration.html#of(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

It expects an amount as `long`, and a `TemporalUnit`, so you need to [convert the TimeUnit into ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toChronoUnit()).

```
static Duration convert(long dur, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    return Duration.of(dur, timeUnit.toChronoUnit());
}
```

Method `toChronoUnit()` was introduced in JDK version 9.

## Java 8

With Java 8 you can translate `TimeUnit` into `ChronoUnit` using [ThreeTen](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) library's utility method [`Temporals.chronoUnit​(TimeUnit)`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#chronoUnit(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

If you don't want to introduce a dependency on this library in your project, you can make use of the utility method provided in the [*answer by Paul*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72757001/17949945).

Comment: Not a Java 8 API I'm afraid :( Guess that's the proper answer anyways, and I need to keep my converter util. EDIT: yeah, `toChronoUnit` is since 9.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski You're right, the convention between `TimeUnit` and `ChronoUnit` was introduced in Java 9. With Java 8 we can't translate one into another using built-in features only, maybe there are some third-party libraries that can facilitate that.

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski [ThreeTen](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) library provides a utility method for that, updated the answer.

Comment: The conversion from `TimeUnit` to `ChronoUnit` is straightforward and [the JDK implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java#L456) is clean.  Rather than introducing a dependency for this simple conversion (in Java 8) I would write a static utility method  based on the JDK source code (which I pasted into my answer).

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Since you think the right track is ugly the solution is to hide the ugliness!  Here's the implementation of `TimeUnit.toChronoUnit()` [from OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java#L456):

```java
/**
 * Converts this {@code TimeUnit} to the equivalent {@code ChronoUnit}.
 *
 * @return the converted equivalent ChronoUnit
 * @since 9
 */
public ChronoUnit toChronoUnit() {
    switch (this) {
    case NANOSECONDS:  return ChronoUnit.NANOS;
    case MICROSECONDS: return ChronoUnit.MICROS;
    case MILLISECONDS: return ChronoUnit.MILLIS;
    case SECONDS:      return ChronoUnit.SECONDS;
    case MINUTES:      return ChronoUnit.MINUTES;
    case HOURS:        return ChronoUnit.HOURS;
    case DAYS:         return ChronoUnit.DAYS;
    default: throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

To keep your code cleaner I would implement a static utility method based on above (i.e. pass in a `TimeUnit` parameter) and get the `ChronoUnit` without doing a conversion in each `case`. You'll end up with 1 call to `Duration.of(long amount, TemporalUnit unit)` and your code will be as beautiful as if you were using Java 9+!

Comment: Indeed, very clean and straightforward, added a link to my answer.